# Identifying a co-ordinate system that works in UK?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I have some data from an old system that contains co-ordinates which I wish to use but I'm unable to establish what sort of co-ordinates they are. They come from the South East region of the UK. For example:

Latitude | Longitude

51181744, 854338

51166014, 1969501

51275331, 707431

51212390, 998914

I have QGIS and ArcGIS available. I've been through a number of tutorials online but have not gotten anywhere with it. It is an American software product but the product is no longer made. I've tried projfinder.com but it isn't working as their server keeps returning a 500 error.

Looking at the extents in ArcGIS shows for all my data:

Top 51467450

Right 2662457

Bottom and left are 0.

I'm aware this is one of the most common questions on here (having already done a lot of reading on this site) but am now out of options. I have a limited understand of this area.

Comment: One rather elementary place to start looking for matches would be to load a shapefile or feature class with a known projection / datum   and load the other data as points and go through various common projections (by changing the Data Frame projection in ArcGIS rather than defining projection over and over again.)  You might want to consider calculating XY coords between Meters and Feet and seeing if it works after it's been converted to from "Feet to Meters" or " Meters to Feet".

Comment: Can you infer anything about their position from the pattern of the dots in that coordinate system? Like seeing the ghost of the outline of the land? And I worry if (0,0) is in the SE of the UK, I don't think any recognised CRS has that, so you might have to work out the transformation from referenced features...

Comment: Have you actually got real points at (0,0) or is that just where the system puts missing data, ie "Null Island"?

Comment: I loaded the points into ArcGIS and plotted them without a known coordinate system and the points do reflect the area of land they are in and where I would expect them to be.

Comment: From the extent of the plotted area, can you estimate the units of measurement (mm, cm, m, ft, yd)?

Answer (score 1):

My intuition would take the lat/lon coordinates as degrees * .1E-6. You then get for the first line:
lat = 51.181744 and lon = .854338 which is somewhere in Kent. The max latitude is about the river Thames, but the max longitude is in the North Sea. If your set contains negative longitudes, I would almost be certain.

Nevertheless, it seems worth a try. You can convert the points to OSGB with PyProj.

Answer (score 0):

Projected coordinates in the UK (well at least GB) are almost always in Ordnance Survey National Grid (OSGB) which is known as EPSG:27700. A quick of a local data file gives me `(  510000.000,  110000.000) (  0d26'10.54"W, 50d52'42.45"N)` so the magnitude looks right.

Comment: Uh the "lat" values are 51 million? Maybe they're in cm, but the "lon" values don't seem to fit as cm or m.

Comment: Missed how many digits there were